# solr child documents pagination returns only 10 docs

Tags: solr, solr4

Hi I want to load parent document with child documents of max 100

what is the parameter I have to pass for the following query to load 100 child documents

```
parent_filter=id:"227305635"&child_filter=reviewid:"227305635"&fq={!parent which=$parent_filter v=$child_filter}&fl=[child parentFilter=$parent_filter childFilter=$child_filter]&q=*:*
```